# Typescript - how to import declared function with same name as namespace

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I'm using cityscape and its typescript definitions.  The types are defined like this:

```
export = cytoscape;
export as namespace cytoscape;

declare function cytoscape(options?: cytoscape.CytoscapeOptions): cytoscape.Core;
declare function cytoscape(extensionName: string, foo: string, bar: any): cytoscape.Core;

declare namespace cytoscape { ... }
```

I'm using it like so:

```
import * as cytoscapeTypes from "cytoscape";
let cytoscape: any = require("cytoscape"); // <- What should *any* be changed to?
```

This works fine:

```
export type CytoscapeProps = { elements: cytoscapeTypes.ElementDefinition[] }
```

I can't figure out how to specify the type for the import of the `cytoscape` method itself.  I've tries all sorts of stuff but can't seem to make it work.  What od I do?

This works to draw the graph, but the type is not correct since I'm using `any` for the import:

```
  this.cytoscapeInstance = cytoscape(
  {
    container: this.cyRef,
    elements: this.props.elements,
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importing the typings and module separately with `import` and `require`, respectively, is unnecessary. In TypeScript when you use `import` it will import the given module *and* the associated typings. In this case, the following should suffice:

```
import cytoscape from "cytoscape";
```

Now when you do this:

```
export type CytoscapeProps = { elements: cytoscape.ElementDefinition[] };
```

...TypeScript is smart enough to know that `cytoscape.ElementDefinition` is a type, because you're using it as a type.

And when you do this:

```
this.cytoscapeInstance = cytoscape({
  container: this.cyRef,
  elements: this.props.elements,
});
```

...TypeScript knows that `cytoscape` is module's main export, which is a function.

Take a look at this CodeSandbox to see it in action: https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-bouman-kg9e5